# Django GET request result for data not in API

Tags: python, django, python-requests

### Context

I am using django to take user input via a form. This data, city_name, is then used to call an API for weather data.

The request works fine when an actual city name is given.

### Blocker/Obstacles

However, these 2 specific cases result in the following error.

1. Invalid city name
2. Search button is clicked without entering anything into the form
   [image]

I have tried using some conditional logic to no avail.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*Views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def index(request):
    if 'city' in request.GET:
        city = request.GET['city']

        # Query API with user input 
        payload = {'q': request.GET['city'], 'appid': 'API_KEY'}
        response = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather', params=payload)

        # Parse json output for key value pairs 
        e = response.json()

        context = {
            'city_name': e['name'], 
            'weather':e['weather'][0]['main'],
            'description' : e['weather'][0]['description'],
            'temp' : e['main']['temp'],
            'pressure':e['main']['pressure'],
            'humidity':e['main']['humidity'],
            'visibility':e['visibility'],
            'wind_speed':e['wind']['speed'],
            'wind_deg':e['wind']['deg']
            }

        # successfull response code
        search_was_successful = (response.status_code == 200)  # 200 = SUCCESS
        context['success'] = search_was_successful
        
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'context': context}) 

    else:
        context = None
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

*HTML(index.html)*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WeatherApp</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h1>Weather in your city</h1>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Enter a city">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Search">
    </form>
    {% if context %}
        {% if context.success %}
            <p>
                <h3>The weather in {{context.city_name}} is:</h3>
                <div>Weather: {{context.weather}}</div>
                <div>Weather description: {{context.description}}</div>
                <div>Temperature: {{context.temp}} <sup>o</sup>C</div>
                <div>Pressure: {{context.pressure}} hPa</div>
                <div>Humidity: {{context.humidity}} %</div>
                <div>Visibility: {{context.visibility}} m</div>
                <div>Wind Speed: {{context.wind_speed}} meter/sec</div>
                <div>Wind Degrees: {{context.wind_deg}} <sup>o</sup></div>
                <div>Conn: {{context.success}} <sup>o</sup></div>
            </p>
        {% else %}
        <p><em>This doesn't work</em></p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I recommend that you validate that the API request was successful before trying to access response data. Practically, this means that the status_code check should come _before_ you create your context dictionary. In case the API status code is not 200, you should handle for that, assuming that the key "name" will not be available on the variable `e`

Comment: Change `e['name']` to `city`?

Comment: The Json response has a dictionary where key = 'name' and value = 'the city name'. This is not the issue as it works fine if a correct city name is given.

Comment: if you send empty city name, api response dictionary will not have 'name' key. so, when you write e['name'], keyError occurs. because there is no key 'name'. but if you send form with data, api response will have key 'name', thus no problem occurs. edit: to prevent this use e.get('name') instead of e['name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate incorrectly entered data or an empty string you can use something like this:
...

```
    e = response.json()

    if e['cod'] == "404" or city == "":
        messages.info(request, 'Incorrect city name, try again.') # or print something 
    else:
        context = {
        'city_name': e['name'], 
        'weather':e['weather'][0]['main'],
        'description' : e['weather'][0]['description'],
        'temp' : e['main']['temp'],
        'pressure':e['main']['pressure'],
        'humidity':e['main']['humidity'],
        'visibility':e['visibility'],
        'wind_speed':e['wind']['speed'],
        'wind_deg':e['wind']['deg']
        }
```

Remember: If you want to use messages in your code, you also need to add information in the html file at the beginning of the body part:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
            {{ message|striptags|safe|linebreaksbr }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to use If, then e.get('name') is alternative solution. This way it will not give KeyError, if key does not exist in dictionary.

Comment: You're right, it's also a good solution :)